# Is there a Pandas equivalent to tidyr's uncount?

Tags: python, r, pandas

Let's assume we have a table with groupings of variable and their frequencies:

In R:

```
> df

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Cough Fever cases
  <lgl> <lgl> <dbl>
1 TRUE  FALSE     1
2 FALSE FALSE     2
3 TRUE  TRUE      3
```

Then we could use `tidyr::uncount` to get a dataframe with the individual cases:

```
> uncount(df, cases)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Cough Fever
  <lgl> <lgl>
1 TRUE  FALSE
2 FALSE FALSE
3 FALSE FALSE
4 TRUE  TRUE 
5 TRUE  TRUE 
6 TRUE  TRUE
```

Is there an equivalent in Python/Pandas?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other solutions, you could combine `take`, `repeat` and `drop`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Cough': [True, False, True],
                   'Fever': [False, False, True],
                   'cases': [1, 2, 3]})

df.take(df.index.repeat(df.cases)).drop(columns="cases")


    Cough   Fever
0   True    False
1   False   False
1   False   False
2   True    True
2   True    True
2   True    True
```

You can also preselect the columns before indexing on the positions:

```py
df.loc(axis=1)[:'Fever'].take(df.index.repeat(df.cases))
   Cough  Fever
0   True  False
1  False  False
1  False  False
2   True   True
2   True   True
2   True   True
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a row index and repeat it according to the counts, for example in R you can do:

```
df[rep(1:nrow(df),df$cases),]
```

first to get a data like yours:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,2,2,2,2],'y':[0,1,0,1,1,1]})
counts = df.groupby(['x','y']).size().reset_index()
counts.columns = ['x','y','n']

    x   y   n
0   1   0   1
1   1   1   1
2   2   0   1
3   2   1   3
```

Then:

```
counts.iloc[np.repeat(np.arange(len(counts)),counts.n),:2]

    x   y
0   1   0
1   1   1
2   2   0
3   2   1
3   2   1
3   2   1
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found an equivalent function in Python, but this works

```
df2 = df.pop('cases')
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.repeat(df2, axis=0), columns=df.columns)
```

`df['cases']` is passed to `df2`, then you create a new DataFrame with the elements from the original DataFrame repeated according to the count in `df2`. Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As easy as you use `tidyr`'s API with [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tribble, uncount
>>> df = tribble(
...     f.Cough, f.Fever, f.cases,
...     True,    False,   1,
...     False,   False,   2,
...     True,    True,    3
... )
>>> uncount(df, f.cases)
   Cough  Fever
  <bool> <bool>
0   True  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
3   True   True
4   True   True
5   True   True
```

I am the author of the package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.